# Example of pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: analysis, sequence-of-function

How can we prove that the sequence of functions defined as 
$$
f_n(x) =
\begin{cases} 
1/n, & x \in\mathbb{Q} \\
1/n+ 1, & x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$

is pointwise convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ and not uniformly convergent on any interval of positive length of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What are the definitions of point-wise convergence and of uniform convergence, and how are they different?  How can you exploit that difference?

Comment: It IS uniformly convergent on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $f_n(x)-f(x) = \frac 1n$ for all $x$ and all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot, since it is *not* true. Your sequence of functions converges uniformly to$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\1&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}\end{array}$$on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: please can you show me how to prove that it converges uniformly??

Comment: sorry I didn't notice it... it's easy to prove that it converges uniformly... Thanks for your help

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: sorry, but I am new to this site.. so please tell me how to do it and I am more than happy to do it

Comment: please can you check this question
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3407643/prove-of-example-of-uniform-convergence-sequence-of-functions

Comment: In order to mark my answer as the accepted one, click the ✓ sign.